# Scala high order functions

Tags: scala

I know that it's an assignment question but I really can't seem to figure out how to do this. I am very new to Scala and having trouble with the syntax.

I want to figure out how to do this:

Write a function `compose` , that takes two functions and applies one after the other. So the `compose`-function has two functions as parameters and a function as output:

```
val f = compose(fib, square)
f(3)    //   f(3) == fib(square(3)) == fib(9) == 34
```

The code that I tried so far:

```
val f = compose(fib, square)

def compose(f: Int => Int, x: Int => Int): Int = {
  f(x())
}

def square(i: Int): Int = {
  i * i
}

def fib(i: Int): Int = {
  if (i < 2) {
    i
  } else {
    fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2)
  }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how the syntax should be, so I can call `f(3)` and get 34 as result.

Comment: I won't answer so that you can crack this yourself - but think about the _return type_ of `compose`: if the type of the input arguments (`f`, `x`) is `Int => Int`, which makes them functions from Int to Int, and `compose` should return a new function from Int to Int, the return type shouldn't just be `Int`, right?

Comment: Oke yes the return type of compose should be a function but still i am dealing with the problem how do i even get a parameter in so i can use that as input param for the f(x(i need an int here))

Comment: Yiou don't. The function you return will get the parameter when you call it. At the time you call `compose` you have no parameter for `x` but you don't need one as you're not calling `x` (yet)

Comment: but x is the square function and requires a parameter which i don't have. How can i give that function a parameter?

Comment: Consider a function that take an argument - a function, and just returns that function. Call it `foo`. So I can go `val k = foo(square)` and get back a function that I can call like this `k(3)`.  That shows how function-returning works. So now all you have to do is work out how to write `compose` taking two functions as arguments and returning another function that calls each of those in turn...

Comment: Or looking at it another way, ignore `compose` for now. How would you write a function that takes an argument `z` and returns  `fib(square(z))`? (and I mean a function, not a method. `val myfunc = ....`)

Comment: val myFunc = (x: Int) => {
   fib(square(x))
 }

Like that i suppose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109247/discussion-between-legopiraat-and-the-archetypal-paul).

Comment: Right. Now paste that line into the body of `compose` and change `fib`->`f` and `square` -> `x`, and that's the function you need to return (and change the return type of `compose` to be the right function type. (sorry, don't have time to chat)

Comment: `val myFunc2 = (x: Int) => compose(fib, square)`

  `def compose(fib: Int => Int, square: Int => Int): Int = {
    fib(square(x))
  }`

This is what you mean? but this doesnt compile because of x in square

Comment: `compose` return type should be a function and you need to return a function just like what you did in `myFunc`

Comment: Could either of you mohit or The Archetypal Paul make an answer for this question. i feel like am close just cant get the syntax like it should

Comment: Try def compose(..) = body of myFunc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here it is:

```
def compose(f: Int => Int, x: Int => Int): Int => Int = {
  i => f(x(i))
}
```

You just name the input argument (`i`) and then you can use it to pass to the function `x`

Comment: Thanks this was the syntax i was looking for. now i understand how the i parameter is injected

Comment: @legopiraat, good, I didn't want to just give you the syntax without you understanding why/how it works....